# Camera app activity

Tags: android, camera, android-sdcard

**Create an activity that opens the camera, takes pictures and saves them to the SD card**

I'm new to Android, I have been assigned a task whereby I need to create a activity which opens camera and takes photo and saves it to memory (*Internal/external*).

Any idea how to proceed please?

Comment: Search on **Google**. You will get any many solutions.

Comment: If you think it is a Repeated question please send the link to the answers and delete this question! I wont mind, I need sollution!

Comment: See my above comment.

Comment: If I got the solution from google why would I come and ask here?

Comment: This is not your IT support service, if you really can't find the duplicates yourself, you're going to have a bad time programming, because you're going to need searching skills more than anything else. But we are not here to just "give u da codez", read the help section and avoid frustration ...

Answer (score 0):

-Use this [Simplecrop library](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage)
Download it and

Call this code to take picture[as per documented in that page..]:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);

// tell CropImage activity to look for image to crop 
String filePath = ...;
intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, filePath);

// allow CropImage activity to rescale image
intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

// if the aspect ratio is fixed to ratio 3/2
intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 3);
intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 2);

// start activity CropImage with certain request code and listen
// for result
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
```

-`Onactivityresult` Method will be as per below code:-

```
if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

    return;
}  

switch (requestCode) {

    case REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE:

        String path = data.getStringExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH);

        // if nothing received
        if (path == null) {

            return;
        }

        // cropped bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFileTemp.getPath());

        break;
}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

**NOTE:-** I explained it because you are new to android and can get it still ask whenever you get stuck at any point regarding this example.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give me the reason of giving it negative points